# Trying to close mobile menu (removing class) when clicking outside of element without effecting nav button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm really struggling to make this work. I have a mobile menu that opens on clicking the button in the header.
This adds an active class to the menu to display it. I have made it full width and locked scrolling. But I want it to close when clicking outside the menu, (removing the class) but I can't get it to work.

This is what I've tried:

```
<script> 
jQuery(document).click(function(event) { 
if(!jQuery(event.target).closest('.navgrid .site__header--mobilenav, .burgerbox').length) {
    if(jQuery('#mobilenavcontainer').hasClass('site__header--mobilenav-active')){
    jQuery('jQuery').removeClass('site__header--mobilenav-active')
}

}        
}); 
</script>
```

But it doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Please Update your HTML and CSS too

Comment: Please supply your HTML and CSS code or link to a codepen or JSfiddle

Answer (score 0):

A simple example but I think covering your requirements.
The button shows the menu. Click at any place outside the menu to hide it.

```js
$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
  const container = $(".menu"); /* Assign outside which element must be clicked */
  if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
    $(".menu").css("display", "none");
  }
});

$("body").on("click", "button", function() {
  $(".menu").css("display", "flex");
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  display: none;
}
li {
background-color: lightblue;
border: thin solid gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click me</button>
<ul class="menu">
  <li>Option 1</li>
  <li>Option 1</li>
  <li>Option 1</li>
</ul>
```